# Why the same animation in Dope Sheet acts diferent with other armatures that are equally structured

Tags: dopesheet

I created an animation in Dope Sheet, which works perfectly on the armature I was working on, then I tried to put the same animation on the other armatures (identical to the initial one), the final result is all bones moving randomly, some bones playing the animation in one side, other bones are moving completely at the opposite way... totally a mess.

As you can apreciate on the photo, some of the legs are crazy! (I've only animated the middle legs).
[image: legs moving so strange]

Comment: Was the orientation (rotation) of the bones identical as well ?

Comment: it seems swer that he has not applied the rotation of the bones, apply the rotation scale and position of the meshes, and the way he applies the weights
you can share the data blocks but I don't know exactly how

Comment: Did you get this sorted?